# How to to replace a text in document with javascript

Tags: javascript

ok my guy

so i want to replace MY GUY to ALRIGHT with  javascript how can i do that

I have tried using

```
document.getElementById('demo').parentNodes.replaceChild(my guy, alright);
```

Comment: did you put the strings in quotes?

Comment: Also, can you place your code in a jsFiddle to make it easier to work with?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace some text inside your tag, just use innerHTML property.

```
var myhtml = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myhtml === 'my guy' ? 'alright' : myhtml;
```

Like so..

replaceChild works not with text, but with html nodes. Checkout this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the entire text using innerText:

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerText = 'all right';
```

If you need to replace an specific part of the string, look at the String.prototype.replace() method.